# Change x or y axis on holoviewplot (hv.BoxWhisker)

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

I am toying around with a bokeh app containing some holoview plots. 
I have now a BoxWhisker plot displaying x=k1 and y=v1, where the DataFrame supplied to the BoxWhisker-plot also contains k2 and v2.

Now when I select via the dropdown select widget, k2 or v2, I'd like to update the BoxWhisker-plot to display the box plot using k2 instead of k1 and v2 instead of v1. How would I achive this?

Here is some code of the setup

```
src = get_data_frame() # contains 4 cols: k1,k2,v1,v2

k_select = Select(value='k1',options=['k1','k2'])
v_select = Select(value='v1',options=['v1','v2'])

k_select.on_change('value', update)
v_select.on_change('value', update)

renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh').instance(mode='server')
plot = hv.BoxWhisker(src, k_select.value, v_select.value)
plot_render = renderer.get_plot(plot, curdoc())

def update(attr, old, new):
   # HOW TO CHANGE THE AXIS IN THE PLOT?

controls = WidgetBox(k_select, v_select)

# Create a row layout
layout_design = row(controls, plot_render.state)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be trivial with [Panel](http://panel.org), which is based on Bokeh but makes it simpler to set up plots controlled with widgets.